# httpListener as a windows service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, httplistener

I have an httpListener exe that is working great.  What I need to do now is make it a service (I think) so that when the server is rebooted, this program will start automatically.  I found a few tutorials for making services and I got one installed, but when I started it, it said it took to long to respond.  I was thinking that might be because I have a while true loop going in the onStart method.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the service onStart event just dives into business logic, the event never ends, so the service does not complete startup.   I don't have a VB.NET example, but my approach has been to create a timer in IniializeComponent event, complete with a smallish interval and wire up of a timer.elapsed event.

The OnStart event then has one line of code in it to start the timer.  The service startup completes, then the service starts getting to work when the Timer.Elapsed event fires.

Comment: I can't have it on an interval because http post request could be coming in at anytime.  After thinking about it over night, what I need is an exe that starts when windows does and runs in the background and minimizes to the task bar, kind of like a anti-virus program.  I think I'm going to look into that route.

Comment: That's not quite it either.  I just added the program to the start up folder on the server, and restarted and tried to send a request on a different machine, but it didn't pick it up.  Then I remotely logged into the server, I saw the program start then sent a request, and it grabbed it.  Then I logged off, and the program stops.  I need to to always be on, regardless if someone is logged in, like IIS, or SQL Server, but I don't think it can be on a timer.

Comment: I finally got it working.  Added the exe as a scheduled job that starts at start-up.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer this question directly without more information (e.g. on what exactly you're doing). However, that should not be necessary as you should be able to debug it yourself by attaching the debugger to the running service, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).